# Помогите распарсить XMLку

Tags: java, xml

https://api.eveonline.com//account/Characters.xml.aspx?keyID=4259396&vCode=8AEAZ02UJ16EH7dDOZMBEUcooD0SUNv83Xnho9MendRy9r4IJbZlzuoW6noEBva7

нужно получить значения в поле row, делаю так

```
public class XMLParse {
public static Document loadTestDocument(String url) throws Exception {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = builder.parse(new URL(url).openStream());        
    return document;
}

Element root = XMLParse.loadTestDocument(url).getDocumentElement();
    Element root = XMLParse.loadTestDocument(url).getDocumentElement();
    System.out.println(root.getElementsByTagName("result").item(0).getChildNodes().item(1).getTextContent());
```

Но вывод пустой

Comment: В вашем примере у row нету `textContent`, может попробовать получить атрибуты через  `.getAttributes()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрый день во-первых у вас повторяется строка (как следствие код вообще не должен компилироваться):

```
Element root = XMLParse.loadTestDocument(url).getDocumentElement();
```

Попробуйте изменить индекс на 0 в последнем выборе элемента:

```
System.out.println(root.getElementsByTagName("result").item(0).getChildNodes().item(1).getTextContent());
```

Должно получиться:

```
System.out.println(root.getElementsByTagName("result").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getTextContent());
```

P.S. Обратите внимание на комментарий "0x5a4d":

> В вашем примере у row нету textContent, может попробовать получить атрибуты через .getAttributes()